# dépeigner la défaite de la humanité

Tags: sens, usage

I have read the following question at Quora:

> Quelles scènes dépeignent la défaite de la humanité?

The only meaning of "dépeigner" in the Larousse and Word Reference dictionaries is "to mess up the hair". It seems that it means "to reveal" in this context. Is it a usual figurative usage in French?

Comment: Yeah, well, it sounds like machine translation of: **What scenes depict the downfall of humanity**? French does not use dépeigner like that.

Comment: @Lambie This is *dépeindre* and it sounds perfectly French (or at least formal French).

Comment: @GAMPUB C'était une mauvaise traduction, comme j'ai dit: Traducteur · Traduit le October 2, 2020 · L'auteur a 62 réponses et 270,2 k vues de réponse

"Cette réponse peut ne pas être une traduction fidèle de la réponse de Shivansh dans Quora en anglais" :
Which scenes depict the defeat of humanity?https://fr.quora.com/Quelles-sc%C3%A8nes-d%C3%A9peignent-la-d%C3%A9faite-de-lhumanit%C3%A9

Comment: Je dirais plutôt que c'est une bonne traduction et une mauvaise interprétation de la phrase traduite... Si une partie est mal traduite, il s'agit *défaite de la humanité*.

Comment: @GAMPUB La phrase originale en anglais utilisait le mot **depict**, traduit incorrectement comme dépeigner en français. La première phrase que j'avais posté venait de moi. Pourtant, j'avais raison pour la mauvaise traduction de depict. Ça au moins, c'est clair, alors on ne peut pas m'accuser de poster un commentaire hors propos...

Comment: "Dépeindre" (et non "dépeigner", cf ma réponse) est une traduction tout à fait correcte du verbe "depict". Une autre option (moins ambigüe) aurait pu être le verbe "représenter", mais la racine du mot étant très similaire entre "depict" et "dépeindre", on peut trouver la première option plus élégante. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From this ambiguous conjugation, you came to an incorrect conclusion: the verb that is used here is actually **dépeindre**.

Here is the [definition from Larousse](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/d%C3%A9peindre/23737):

> Décrire quelque chose, quelqu'un en détail, en rendre compte tel qu'il est ou selon une certaine interprétation : *On l'a dépeint comme un être cruel.*

or

> Donner une certaine image de quelque chose, quelqu'un, le représenter : *Le bilan dépeint bien la situation de l'entreprise.*

In your case, the second meaning seems to be the correct one. We could rephrase that Quora question as *"Quelles scènes représentent bien la défaite de l'humanité ?"*, for example.

The verb **dépeindre** is conjugated the same way as the verb **peindre**, as following for present tense:

```
je (dé)peins
tu (dé)peins
il/elle/on (dé)peint
nous (dé)peignons
vous (dé)peignez
ils/elles (dé)peignent
```

As for the verb **dépeigner**, which does exist, here is how to conjugate it:

```
je (dé)peigne
tu (dé)peignes
il/elle/on (dé)peigne
nous (dé)peignons
vous (dé)peignez
ils/elles (dé)peignent
```

Given that the plural conjugations are the exact same for both verbs, it's easy to understand why you got confused!

Comment: The poster is quoting a sentence from Quora. He did not make it up.

Comment: I never said they made it up. OP quoted a sentence from Quora, and came to the wrong conclusion that it was the verb "dépeigner" conjugated in its plural form. I explained that it was actually the verb "dépeindre", but that the confusion was understandable because these two verbs are conjugated the same way in their plural form. :) Maybe my usage of the verb "deduct" wasn't right, so I rephrased my first sentence to make it clearer.

Comment: I already did that (because there is already a thread of comments talking about the translation quality) and I believe there is nothing wrong in it. In French, the question **"Quelles scènes dépeignent la défaite de l'humanité ?"** is correct. It's just that Alan (OP) made a mistake in their interpretation (they thought it was from the verb "dépeigner" whereas it was actually from "dépeindre"), hence my answer and my explanation. Now let's not go too far on this discussion because we are starting to drift away from the topic. :)

Comment: Yes, the problem was with the OP, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

Dans ce contexte, il ne s'agit pas du verbe « [dépeigner](https://www.dictionnaire-academie.fr/article/A9D1458) », mais du verbe « [dépeindre](https://www.dictionnaire-academie.fr/article/A9D1459) »